# Pandas: filter by value, then get max value in Multiindex

Tags: pandas, sorting, filter, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a dataset that looks like this, where `DATE` and `LETTER` are the multi-indexed.

I want to return a list of max `LETTER A VALUES` per date.

So, in this instance, I want the `VALUES 3` and `8` returned.

```
                            VALUE                   
DATE      LETTER            
1-2002       A                1                            
             B                7
             A                3  
             B                4                                  
2-2002       A                6                   
             B                2                  
             A                8
             B                5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select with[`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) first and aggregate `max`:

```
df = df.xs('A', level=1).groupby(level=0).max().reset_index()
print (df)
     DATE  VALUE
0  1-2002      3
1  2-2002      8

L = df.xs('A', level=1).groupby(level=0)['VALUE'].max().tolist()
print (L)
[3, 8]
```

Old solution:

I think you first [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) for filtering and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first and second index and aggregate `max`:

```
df = df[df.index.get_level_values('LETTER') == 'A']
df = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).max()
print (df)
               VALUE
DATE   LETTER       
1-2002 A           3
2-2002 A           8
```

---

```
df = df[df.index.get_level_values('LETTER') == 'A']
df = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).max().reset_index()
print (df)
     DATE LETTER  VALUE
0  1-2002      A      3
1  2-2002      A      8
```

Comment: Perfect!  Worked well.

Answer (score 0):

So to get only max values for `A`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df[(df['LETTER'] == 'A')].groupby(['DATE', 'LETTER']).max()
```

And to get that numbers in a list:

```
max_A = df[(df['LETTER'] == 'A')].groupby(['DATE', 'LETTER']).max()['VALUE'].tolist()
```